# Helping good Documentation rise to the top

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

There's a LOT of examples going up on Documentation ... some good and some bad.

It seems to me that we might need an additional way of letting good examples rise to the top and bad answers fall to the bottom.

Using reputation is one way: more upvotes lets answers rise.

But after answering questions on SO for a couple of years, I've come to understand that a large percentage of questions come from new programmers who need answers to basic questions.

After getting an answer, new comers & newbies often leave without voting on an answer or leaving feedback of any kind. That's ok ... but it's not informative about the usefulness of the answer or the quality of the answer.

I suspect that Documentation will have even more "view & run" users whose opinion about the Example will be unknown.

I propose that viewers of Documentation Examples with less than 10(?) rep are given a quick popup dialog asking them (Yes||No) if the example was useful to them and/or additionally asking them to rate the quality of the example (1-5).

Many sites do this to get feedback about their Documentation.

This would give the powers-that-be on Documentation another tool to let good Examples rise and bad Examples fall.

Comment: There's an anonymous feedback widget on Q&A as well; it's triggered by the vote buttons if you're not a logged-in user. I'm not sure if the results are formally used for anything, though.

Comment: I despise "quick feedback popups" on websites.  I tend to avoid sites that use them excessively.

Answer (score 7):

> It seems to me that we might need an additional way of letting good examples rise to the top and bad answers fall to the bottom.

The slip of the tongue here ("bad answers") betrays the problem in this thinking, and therefore the problem with having voting on examples at all.

We don't want bad examples to fall to the bottom. We don't want bad examples *at all*. All the examples should be good. *Different*, but good. Bad examples should be turned into good examples or removed entirely. We shouldn't tolerate their presence by merely downvoting them.

Granted, that only proves that voting on examples is a stupid idea, but whatever, we gotta give people that rep somehow...

Comment: Fair enough! I intended that my proposal focus on additional ways of promoting good examples. I haven't checked the Documentation procedures yet. Is there a way for bad answers to eventually be deleted, or do they stick around forever?

Comment: @markE: You delete them by *deleting them*. It's something you do when you edit them. Which means anyone can do it.

Comment: So it's not like regular SO where downvoted posts eventually get auto-deleted?

Comment: Oooooo -- about ANYONE deleting ... so if someone doesn't like an Example I diligently worked hard to create, they can just trash it?

Comment: @markE: "So it's not like regular SO where downvoted posts eventually get auto-deleted?" That's not true of answers on SO at all, only questions. "*so if someone doesn't like an Example I diligently worked hard to create, they can just trash it?*" If people approve that change, yes.

Comment: So if one person votes to delete an Example and their co-worker approves the delete-change then some hard work can be trashed -- not good, IMO. *An aside: Yes, I meant to refer to downvoted questions (not answers). Thanks for the catch :-)*

Comment: @markE: "*So if one person votes to delete an Example and their co-worker approves the delete-change then some hard work can be trashed -- not good*" What do you expect from a system that allows 1-rep users review changes?

Comment: Ouch! **Note to self:** *Make backup copies of any Examples I post*